# How can I get rid of Chromium?

Tags: windows, chromium

How can I get rid of Chromium? I have already tried to get rid of it by using the control panel. I went to the programs list, selected Chromium, and hit uninstall. The computer said it had a problem, and then asked if I wanted to remove it from the programs list. Is there any other way to get rid of it?

Comment: Well, you’re obviously missing the uninstall program. Is Chromium really still there? Did you mess with it in any way? Just install the latest version and try uninstalling again.

Comment: Or install the version your trying to uninstall :-) (then uninstall)  An uninstaller can fail to work if the various parts and pieces of the installer are not there, like the package itself and any program used to install. Various clean-up programs and cleaning techniques can remove parts and pieces needed again to uninstall a program, and depending on the program there can be dependencies for the install and they dont dissapear when uninstalling.

Comment: @DanielB I am typing in Chromium, so yes, it's still here.  No, I didn't mess with it (Don't know how to do that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:-

- Download the Chromium exe from the download site.(https://download-chromium.appspot.com/)
- Double click the exe in your downloads folder.
- Uninstall.

OR

- Go to C:/Program Files.
- Delete the Chromium folder.
- Go to C:/Program Files(x86).
- Delete the Chromium folder.
- Click on Start -> Run..
- Type %AppData%
- Delete the Chromium folder.
- Type %LocalAppData%
- Delete the Chromium folder.
- Delete The Shortcut.

Sorry if it is a little cumbersome, but
Hope this Works!!

Comment: I attempted this method, but it isn't working.  Here's what I did: 1. Followed the link and downloaded chromium.  2. Went to Windows Explorer and found the file. 3. Didn't figure out how to do it that way, so went to C:/Program Files  4. Didn't find it there, so went to program files(x86)  5. Also couldn't find it there (I even searched both locations.)    I also couldn't find the Start_>Run section...   Could you give me some help?     P.S. I was using Chromium at the time (and am typing in it now).  Would that hinder the download?

Comment: Something is probably wrong with your computer. No, Chromium won't hinder the download, in case you were thinking that. I guess you set up chromium with a different installation folder.

Comment: Try searching for "chromium" in the search box in My Computer.
Then, delete everything that has chromium on it(before verifying that it IS a chromium folder).

Comment: Just deleting files wouldn't fully uninstall a program. There are registry entries that will be left behind. You can try using an uninstaller program. Like Revo, or use system restore to roll back and try again

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `%LocalAppData%`, I was looking for it!

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, find where it lives in your program files (either "Program Files" or "Program Files (x86)"). It is most likely safe to delete the files when you find them. You can then either run a registry-fixer tool, or better yet, use regedit (Start Menu > Run > regedit.exe) and delete the specific entries for it yourself. Of course, those registry entries probably aren't harming anything, so it's probably safe to just ignore them.